# How can I get my threaded program to print specific output

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, wait, notify

I am having problem dealing with synchronization java threads, applying wait and notify..

I want to figure out how could I implement these in a program where I can print out the answer alternately.. for example person1 will count numbers 1-5 as well as person2, the output should be like this.

```
person1 count 1
person2 count 1
person1 count 2
person2 count 2
person1 count 3
person2 count 3
person1 count 4
person2 count 4
person1 count 5
person2 count 5
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: You cant do this. The java scheduler has its own algorithm to decide which thread to run. SOunds like you want a single threaded loop.

Comment: Do you want us to tell you all about threads in Java ? Do you want us to write a program for you ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: In Java 7 you could use the `Phaser` for this. Prior to Java 7 the best fit would probably be `CountDownLatch`. But, if this is not just a simplification of some real concurrent scenario, there is no reason to use multithreading.

Comment: Java threads aren't meant to do do stuff like this. You could do it using locks, however you'd have to be very cautious not to create deadlocks. Personaly i would implement this totally different.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for responding. I don't want you to write the whole program, I just need your idea on what should I do in order to achieve that output. I have a hard time understanding java threads, but I will give more time to understand it. I am just new to java and I want to learn. and with your help, I know I can do it. Thanks guys for the respond. I will update you in my progress. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this easily in two ways:

1. Pass a 'print token' between the threads using two semaphores:  thread 1 prints, signals semaphore A, waits on semaphore B then loops.  Thread 2 waits on semaphore A, prints, signals semaphore B and loops.
2. Write in-line, single-threaded code.

Comment: I think that would be the solution in my problem. but i have no idea in semaphore, can you give me links where tutorials and examples were provided? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use wait and notify. Use syncronized blocks.

For an in-depth explaination of how the Java Monitor works, including code examples, you can go here: http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/threadsynch.html

Comment: That does not answer the question - in particular I fail to see how using a synchronized block will alternate the threads.

Comment: Technically `wait/notify` includes the use of `synchronized` blocks since you need to hold the lock in order to call `wait/notify`.

Comment: Tudor: I know that synchronized technically just wraps wait/notify, I just think the semantics are cleaner and easier to understand.

assylias: The treads will alternate in the order they are prioritized by the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of threaded programs is *asynchronous* operation of the threads.  That's how you get a performance boost because the different tasks can work on different CPUs/cores concurrently, *without* having to synchronize on each other.  To force this sort of synchronized, lock step output is by definition forcing threads to do something atypical.

@Martin's answer provides alternatives to get it to work.